# In Swift, How do I use a Completion Handler in a function that's already Using One?

Tags: swift, closures, return-value, completionhandler

The title is most likely not worded right, but I'll post my code and you can judge for yourself...

I want to return a `String`from a function that has a closure (where that closure is getting a value from another function:

```
    //call the ServerTimeReturn function and print the results------------ current, from
func handleDateAndTimeFetch() -> String {

    var thisIsTheDate : String?

    serverTimeReturn { (getResDate) -> Void in //Handles the value received from Google and formats it

        let dFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dFormatter.dateStyle = .short
            dFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
            dFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

        thisIsTheDate = dFormatter.string(from: getResDate!)
    }
        if thisIsTheDate != nil {
            return thisIsTheDate!
        } else {return "AppDelegate > handleDateAndTimeFetch() > 'thisIsTheDate' was not passed a value (was nil)"}
} //End of function


//Call Google's server for the current date & time in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)----------------------------
func serverTimeReturn(completionHandler:@escaping (_ getResDate: Date?) -> Void){

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
        let httpsResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if let contentType = httpsResponse?.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String {

            let dFormatter = DateFormatter() //A formatter object
            dFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"

            let serverTime = dFormatter.date(from: contentType)
            completionHandler(serverTime)

            guard let _ = data, error == nil else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }

        }
    }
        print("Retrieved date value")
    task.resume()
}
```

To summarize the above, I call `handleDateAndTimeFetch()` elsewhere, and when it's called, IT calls `serverTimeReturn` where it retrieves the current date and time from Google's servers. That `serverTimeReturn` uses a `completionHandler` that ensures the data is retrieved before returning it to its call in `handleDateAndTimeFetch()`. Now back in `handleDateAndTimeFetch()`, I do a little bit of formatting before I assign it to the value `thisIsTheDate` (which I define outside the closure so that `handleDateAndTimeFetch()` can return it to the place I started this whole process elsewhere.

Problem is, I think `handleDateAndTimeFetch()` is trying to return `thisIsTheDate` before it finishes being collected from `serverTimeReturn`, because the value is always 'nil' and it prints my `else` statement.

My question is, when I call `serverTimeReturn` inside `handleDateAndTimeFetch()`, how can I add a `completionHandler` there as well so that I for sure have a value before I return the `thisIsTheDate` string?

Believe me, I've tried very hard to figure it out but my newbie mind is not allowing it haha.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a completion to a server method doesn't mean you can use it's return directly in another method , the call to `serverTimeReturn` is asynchronous so you can't return the string directly from `handleDateAndTimeFetch` , you have to either set a completion for  `handleDateAndTimeFetch`

```
func handleDateAndTimeFetch(completionHandler:@escaping (_ getResDate: String?) -> Void) {
     serverTimeReturn { (getResDate) -> Void in //Handles the value received from Google and formats it

        let dFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
        dFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let thisIsTheDate = dFormatter.string(from: getResDate!)
        completion(thisIsTheDate)
  }
}
```

Or make all the formatting inside `serverTimeReturn` and return the string (which I recommend ) , as no need to do 2 functions to wait for the same asynchronous task

Comment: Thanks for the example! I ended up working on your preferred suggestion and got it working :)

Comment: Ok , happy coding